# Bijective map from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There  exists  a  map $f: \Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Q $  such  that  $f$  is

A. Bijective  and  increasing

B. Onto  and  decreasing

C. Bijective  and  satisfies  $f(n)\ge 0$  if $n\le 0$

D. Has  uncountable images

Now  option  D.  is  absurd . Option  C.  is  given  to  be  the  correct  answer.I  was  thinking  since  both  sets  are  countable  bijection  is  obvious. Now  why  cannot  be  increasing  ? I  could  map  $0$  to  $0$  and  the  negative  integers  to the  negative  rationals and  positive  integers  to  the  positive  rationals. And  if  increasing  would  be  possible  just  interchanging signs  would  give  the  decreasing  map. So  none  is  possible  but  why?

Comment: A: If $f(1)<f(2)$, then there are infinitely many rational numbers between them.

Comment: I  don't  know . I  posted  it  now  for  the  first  time . Why  deleted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that, while the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same, the topology is different.  Consider the following: Given two integers $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$, can we say how many integers $c$ satisfy $a < c < b$?  Now ask the same question for the rational numbers.

This leads to problems.  For example, lets say $a$ and $b$ are two such integers with $k$ other integers between them.  And we can even assume the $f(a) = r_{1} < r_{2} = f(b)$.  But now we can find an increasing sequence of$k+1$ rational numbers (at least) between $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$, and only $k$ potential integers to use as their preimages.

Comment: ok .  But  why  is  C. valid? Just  like  the  positive  rationals  are  images  of  negative   rationals  and  nothing  contradicts , that is  how?

Answer (score 6):

For A, some $f(n)$ lies between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, which requires the integer $n$ to lie between $0$ and $1$.For B, let $M$ be the least positive $n$ for which $f(n)<f(0)$. Then $f(M)<f(m)=(f(M)+f(0))/2<f(0)$ for some integer $m$, so $M>m>0$. But by the definition of $M$, if any integer $m$ satisfies $M>m>0$ then $f(m)\geq f(0)$.